# Are the Disciples of Christ trinitarian?

Tags: denomination-survey, trinity

**Are the Disciples of Christ trinitarian?**

The identity statement from their [website](http://www.disciples.org/) is:

> We are Disciples of Christ, a movement for wholeness in a fragmented world. As part of the one body of Christ we welcome all to the Lord’s Table as God has welcomed us.

I cannot find any references to a trinitarian understanding of the Christian God on their website. I assume this is intentional, in line with another statement of theirs:

> we don’t require acceptance of any formal creed for membership in the church

It appears that they are not taking a stance. This might make them non-trinitarian in the eyes of many, though I would not be surprised if members instead regard their own position as non-committal or members simply differ in opinion. Instead of speculating further, I am hereby asking the community for knowledge or opinions, official or unofficial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall from my time (decades ago) as an ordained and licensed Disciple of Christ minister, anyone who had publicly professed that Jesus was their Savior and Lord was freely received--with no dogmatic strings attached--into fellowship with any Disciple's of Christ assembly.

What if they believed in the Trinity?

> "Welcome! Come worship with us and feast at the Lord's Table!"

What if they did **not** believe in the Trinity?

> "Welcome! Come worship with us and feast at the Lord's Table!"

Why? Because asking someone to confirm their personal believe in the Trinity was a "test of faith". Such tests aren't necessary to one's salvation.

In brief: not every Disciple of Christ is a Trinitarian, nor is every Trinitarian a "disciple" of Christ.

Comment: Right answer. (+1) I like their idea of "no dogmatic strings attached". Trinity is indeed "a test of faith".

Comment: sounds like the Disciples of Christ is a group of different doctrines.

Comment: The Christian Church (Disciples of Christ), or CC(DoC), is orthodox Christian, yet has been "different" than many orthodox denominations since the Cane Ridge Revival. Simply, they believe any person, from any Christian denomination, should be able to fellowship with the CC(DoC) and feel comfortable/at home when they walk out the door. There is never a test of faith. They might ask if the person has publicly professed Jesus as their personal Lord and Savior, but even that isn't a requirement for participation in worship, study, and Communion. If interested, you can ask Dr. Google for more info.